# Node Benchmarking tool to examine the sub requests/methods timing

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, hapi, httpbackend

I used the apache bench , siege and benchmark.js for the benchmarking, load test to examine.But these tools/libraries gave the overall result/time which took from start to end. I want the execution time for all the sub methods or requests calling from the main request/method.Kindly suggest any tool or library.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand what you mean with "sub method" execution time.

If you just want to know the percentiles of the latency of your HTTP server (Node.js or not), you can use something like [autocannon](https://github.com/mcollina/autocannon).

Instead, if you want to know the execution time of the functions you call in your route handlers, you'll probably want tracing and profiling capabilities. For this you can try [node-clinic](https://github.com/clinicjs/node-clinic) (it's a suite of 3 tools) or [FlameScope](https://github.com/Netflix/flamescope).

Anyway, Stack Overflow isn't the best website for open-ended questions. You might have more luck on [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/468/linux-network-monitor-with-web-interface/469#469).